# Why do voltage vary in series and not in parallel

Tags: electricity, electrical-resistance

My question is kind of old and asked but I still didn't get the answers, if I don't consider the ohm's law or hydraulic analogy and answer this question solely by logic. Why should voltage differ in series and not in parallel with same resistors? The energy for charges to move through the resistors in both the orientation must have been same. Then why should there be a difference in voltage of both the cases?

Comment: It is not clear what situation you have in mind. In some cases voltage is different, in others it is not.

Comment: If I have a set of resistors and I arrange all of them in parallel then, why should the voltage be same for each of them? Whereas if I were to arrange all of them in series, voltage would have been different for all individual resistors. Why does this happen?

Comment: @ShreyaSoni Because the electric "pressure" from the battery is constant. If there is a wire straight from battery pole to resistor, then nothing blocks the "pressure" along the way. If there is a resistor in the way, then that resistor blocks some of the "pressure". Just like a filter blocks or reduces some of the pressure in a water hose. The water analogy works quite well to explain simple parallel and series circuits.

Comment: @Steeven Thank you!

Comment: @Vadim Thank you for correcting me!

Answer (score 2):

In comments, you clarified your question as,

> If I have a set of resistors and I arrange all of them in parallel then, why should the voltage be same for each of them?

If you have resistors connected in parallel, you can say they are all connected between some point "a" and another point "b".

And the potential difference between two points is defined (when it can be defined) as

$$V_b-V_a = V_{ba}=-\int_a^b \vec{E}\cdot d\vec\ell$$

Because of the assumptions we made in assuming we're working with a lumped circuit (no changing magnetic field through our circuit and all dimensions in the circuit much shorter than the wavelengths associated with the highest frequency signals in our circuit), we've assured that the voltage is a defined quantity, and that this integral will have the same value regardless of which path we follow between *a* and *b* in calculating the integral.

And therefore the voltage across all the resistors in the parallel combination must be the same.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

When resistors are in parallel, each is subject to the voltage from the source.  When in series the voltage steps down from one to the next, so the each feels only a fraction of the voltage from the source.

Comment: So things work due to the effect of both end terminals and not only on the final terminal?

Comment: @ShreyaSoni if both terminals had the same potential, then there would be no voltage. Voltage is the difference in potential. Just like a ball wants to fall down from the shelf, only if the shelf is at a higher height than the floor. If the heights are the same nothing will want to fall; if the potentials are the same, no charge will want to flow.

Comment: Yes, the current in a resistor depends on the difference in potential (voltage) between the two ends of the resistor.

Comment: Thank you for helping me!